# Search in child model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

A company model has many tag and has a country_id field. I would like to find:

1. all companies, located in a certain county
2. all companies, located in a certain county and has a certain tag `if params[:tag]` is present.

The first query is pretty easy

```
 Company.where(:country_id => params[:country_id])
```

As for second one, I tried some queries and nothing worked

```
companies = Company.where(:country_id => params[:country_id])
companies = Company.tags.where(:name=> params[:tag])
undefined method `tags' for #<Class:0x000000055dfb60>
```

If I put

```
Company.tags.where(:name=> params[:tag])
```

then the error is the same

```
undefined method `tags' for #<Class:0x000000055dfb60>
```

In Rails console a command `Company.first.tags` receives all tags as it does.

**UPDATE**: this works

```
Company.joins(:tags).where("tags.name = ?", query_hash[:tag])
```

But I don't understand yet how to do something like this

```
 my_conditions = get_search_conditions
 if query_hash[:tag].present?
    companies = Company.all(:conditions => my_conditions).joins(:tags).where("tags.name = ?", query_hash[:tag]) 
 else
    companies = Company.all(:conditions => conditions) 
 end
```

The error is

```
undefined method `all' for #<Array:0x007fbec8063e00>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error is `undefined method all for #<Array:0x007fbec8063e00>`

It should work if you replace `Company.all` with `Company.where`

Answer (score 0):

check if this works - Company.joins(:tags).where("tags.name",params[:tag])